# significance code missing in aov() output in R

Tags: r, output, anova, p-value, significance

when i run the following code, the summary of my aov() output does not show significance codes for the p-values.

What can I do so that I the output will give significance codes?

```
group1 <- c(rnorm(n = 15, mean = 50, sd = 7))
group2 <- c(rnorm(n = 15, mean = 50, sd = 7))
group3 <- c(rnorm(n = 15, mean = 50, sd = 7))


df1 <- cbind(group1, group2, group3) %>% 
data.frame() %>%
stack()

aov1 <- (aov(values ~ ind, data = df1))
summary(aov1)
```

Output:

```
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
ind          2   53.8   26.88    0.66  0.522
Residuals   42 1711.0   40.74
```

How come I do not see an ** next to the p-value indicating the level of significance, such as in this example below?

```
              Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
A             1    451   450.7   3.765 0.058213 .  
B             2   2034  1017.1   8.498 0.000693 *** 
Residuals    48   5745   119.7                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

thanks.

Comment: Because your test was not significant (Pr(F) = 0.522)

Comment: ah got it! thanks, that makes sense.